# How does the nested for loop prints data in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to display a user's followers and a few of their followers and followings in a template using nested loops, but the displayed information is incorrect. When I print the queryset in the terminal, it shows the correct information. As I have not previously worked with nested loops in templates, I would appreciate guidance on how to correctly display this information.

view.py :

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FollowerView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = context['user']
        myfollowers = user.is_following.all()
        for target_list in myfollowers:
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=target_list)
            followers_obj = user_obj.is_following.all()
            followerings_obj = user_obj.userprofile.follower.all()
            print(followers_obj,user_obj) #this return two query sets. which are given below
        context['myfollowers_data']= followers_obj
        context['myfollowerings_data']= followerings_obj
        return context
```

output in terminal:

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<QuerySet [<UserProfile: admin>]> flash 
<QuerySet [<UserProfile: admin>, <UserProfile: flash>]> maddy
```

this is right information. the problem is with template.

follow template:

```
{% for follower in user.is_following.all %}
                <div class="followers-body">
                 <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{follower.avatar.url}}" alt="">
                 <div class="name-box">
                 
                  <h4>{{follower}}</h4>
                  <span>@{{follower}}</span>
                  <div class="followers-base">
                   <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item full-width">
                     <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                     {% if myfollowers_data %}
                     {% for user in myfollowers_data %}
                      <img src="{{user.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="img-circle max-w-40 ">
                      {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                      <span> {{myfollowers_data.count}} Followers </span>#this returning 2,it suppose to return 1 as flash(user object) has one follower
                     </div><!--/ pull-left -->
                    </li> 
                    <li class="list-group-item full-width">
                     <div class="pull-left">
                       {% for user in myfollowerings_data %}
                      <img src="{{user.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="img-circle max-w-40 ">
                      {% endfor %}
                      <span> {{myfollowerings_data.count}} Following </span>
                     </div><!--/ pull-right -->
                    </li><!--/ list-group-item -->                     
                   </ul>
                  </div><!--/ followers-base -->
                 </div><!--/ name-box -->
                 <span><a href="#" class="kafe-btn kafe-btn-mint-small"> Follow</a></span>
                </div><!--/ followers-body -->
                {% endfor %}
```

if more detail is require than tell me in a comment session, i will update my question with that information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable in your inner loop:

```
...
        <li class="list-group-item full-width">
            <div class="pull-left">
                {% for usr in myfollowerings_data %}
                    <img src="{{usr.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="img-circle max-w-40 ">
                {% endfor %}
                 <span> {{myfollowerings_data.count}} Following </span>
             </div><!--/ pull-right -->
        </li><!--/ list-group-item -->
...
```

Nested loops in which the target variables have the same name in fact share a single variable